# What's the difference between $\omega$ and $i\omega$?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-field-theory

In conformal field theory in 2d, one introduced $\omega$ to $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\omega\}$ to corporate for the poles.

However, would there be any difference between $\omega$ and $i\omega$? Why did one not consider $i\omega$ being in the set as well?